# Word Request: To do with physical appearance

Tags: single-word-requests

The word doesn't carry much connotation, maybe something like "that person cares about looks". What I mean is it doesn't carry any double meaning, it is very strictly related to appearance only, maybe a little bit about being self-important/self-obsessed?

I'm relatively sure you could use it like this in a sentence "She got boob implants, she's so ____"

The word is not vain, narcissistic, superficial, conceited, snobby, cosmetic, shallow, flamboyant, ostentatious, classy, exhibitionistic, gay, extravagant.

It's not a very complicated word, probably 6-10 letters.

The definition would be something like "To do with (outward/physical) appearance".

Comment: Are you sure you are not thinking about *vanity*? I didn't offer it because you excluded it, but it pretty much fits your request.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ***image-conscious*** to describe someone trying to improve their physical appearance as a way to improve their self-image:

> concerned about the way one comes across to other people and the impression one creates
>   <sub>[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/image-conscious)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As it's not *Shallow*, it's perhaps **Frivolous** (more used for women than for men ...)

- carefree and superficial
- If someone is frivolous, that person shouldn't be taken seriously because he's always fooling around and never gets anything done. Frivolous is pretty much the opposite of essential.