# Word to describe a person to whom good looks matters

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the one word to describe a person to whom good looks matters; who sees good looks as the first criteria to accept someone in his/her life?

Comment: Please provide an example sentence. Please say whether the term you are looking for should be slang, derogatory, or neutral.  Please say what terms, words, and idioms you have discarded, and why. Please share your research with us, so users can give you great answers.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of this: [Word Request: To do with physical appearance](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266101/word-request-to-do-with-physical-appearance)

Answer (score 1):

shallow

Judging a person based strictly on looks, not factoring in their personality whatsoever.

-- urbandictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

I think *superficial* fits here:

> concerned only with the obvious or apparent
>
> presenting only an appearance without substance or significance

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial))</sub>

The link even provides a sample usage which fits your situation:

> Angelina Jolie goes blond and bubbly and hell hasn't even started freezing over. The brooding brunette donned a Monroe-esque platinum coif for her most recent film, “Life or Something Like It.” She plays a **superficial** reporter who learns what's most important in life—which is, apparently, getting it on with Edward Burns. —Katerine Stroup et al., Newsweek, 23 July 2001

Comment: - 1 for citing "a superficial reporter" as a parallel example, it does not mean someone who cares about physical appearance. That movie review was clearly written in an ironic/sarcastic tone.